# HTTP 400 on IBM Cloud (Cloud Foundry) with Node.js an Express

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a simple app with two routes, which I use locally and on IBM Cloud/Cloud Foundry (512 M RAM)

1. `/`

   - returns "Hello World!" & 200 locally and on the IBM Cloud
2. `/getData`

   - returns some data locally & 200
   - on cloud it returns 400, no logs

Edit:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
var cors = require("cors"); // Cors
app.use(cors());
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

// *************** GETDATA ***************************************
app.get('/getData', function (req, res) {
    var request = require("request");

    var httpHeaderOptions = {
        accept: "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        apikey: req.headers.apikey
    };

    var restoptions = {
        method: "GET",
        url: req.headers.route,
        headers: httpHeaderOptions
    };

    //    console.log("headers: " + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    //    console.log("GET DOCS: \n", JSON.stringify(restoptions));

    request(restoptions, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(typeof (body));
        body_json = JSON.parse(body);
        if (error) {
            console.error("Failed: %s", error.message);
            body = {
                "error": error.message
            };
            res.status(400).json(body);
        } else {
            console.log("Success: \n", body);
            res.status(200).json(body_json);
        }
    });
});

// *************** POST  DOC ***************************************
app.post('/postData', function (req, res) {
    var request = require("request");

    var httpHeaderOptions = {
        accept: "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        apikey: req.headers.apikey
    };

    var restoptions = {
        method: "POST",
        url: req.headers.route,
        headers: httpHeaderOptions,
        body: req.body,
        json: true
    };

    console.log("headers: " + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    console.log("POST DOC: \n", JSON.stringify(restoptions));
    request(restoptions, function (error, response, body) {
        if (typeof (body) == 'object' && Object.keys(body).length === 0) {
            // unknown error, empty resposne
            res.status(400).json(body);
        } else {
            console.log("body: " + JSON.stringify(body));
            if (error) {
                console.error("Failed: %s", error.message);
                body = {
                    "error": error.message
                };
                res.status(400).json(body);
            } else {
                console.log("Success: \n", JSON.stringify(body));
                res.status(200).json(body);
            }

        }
    });
});

// *********************
app.post('/watsonAssistant', function (req, res) {
    var request = require("request");
    var reqURL = "https://hackathon-jps.eu-de.mybluemix.net/watsonAssistant";

    console.log("URL: \n", reqURL);
    console.log("POST Body: \n", JSON.stringify(req.body));

    var httpHeaderOptions = {
        accept: "application/json",
        "content-type": "application/json",
    };

    var restoptions = {
        method: "POST",
        url: reqURL,
        headers: httpHeaderOptions,
        body: req.body,
        json: true
    };

    console.log("send request \n");

    request(restoptions, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("in request \n");
        if (error) {
            console.error("Failed: %s", error.message);
            body = {
                "error": error.message
            };
            res.status(400).json(body);
        } else {
            console.log("Success: \n", body[0]);
            res.status(200).json(body[0]);
        }
    });
});


// Start the server
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('simple forward server is running')
});
```

- [link](https://github.com/gitjps/hackathons_and_node-red/tree/master/simple_forward_server) to the code

Comment: Share the code, how is it set up? I have some old, not maintained code here from the time I tested it: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/Bluemix-ContextPathRouting

Comment: I added a link to the code, thx

Comment: embed it - nobody is looking at links and the question needs to be even understood if the link is gone

Comment: done, btw, meanwhile I was able to Dockerize the app and it is running on a different machine properly.

Answer (score 0):

This will be because whatever `req.headers.route` is set to, is not visible to the app when it is running in the cloud. Your first check should be on `error`. Your second check should be if `body` is not null, and an object  instead you immediately JSON.parse `body`, which may be throwing a parsing exception.

Comment: thx for the resolution, as I‘m not a developer I‘d appreciate a rational, why headers are not visible in the cloud